# Change supported locales

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm changing [this line](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/00c8404ee13ab1383fca94daaeb70f156701d707/lib/main.dart#L62) according to the relevant [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#specifying-the-apps-supportedlocales-parameter) by this patch:

```dart
           return MaterialApp(

             // ...

             initialRoute: initialRoute,
-            supportedLocales: GalleryLocalizations.supportedLocales,
+            supportedLocales: [
+              const Locale('en'),
+              const Locale('he'),
+            ],
             locale: GalleryOptions.of(context).locale,
             localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
               deviceLocale = locale;
               return locale;
             },

// ...
```

But the locales options on settings page are *not* modified. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supported locales of **settings** page are on file `lib/pages/settings.dart` and can be limited by modifying [this line](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/00c8404ee13ab1383fca94daaeb70f156701d707/lib/pages/settings.dart#L124) with this patch:

```dart
-    var supportedLocales =
-        List<Locale>.from(GalleryLocalizations.supportedLocales);
+    var supportedLocales = [
+      const Locale('en'),
+      const Locale('he'),
+    ];
     supportedLocales.removeWhere((locale) => locale == deviceLocale);
```